# Как оптимизовать mysql запрос?

Tags: mysql

Имею записи по книгам, но, данные разнесены по разным таблицам. Теперь надо сделать поиск и ищу по  9 полям по полному равенству или с символом %

мой пример запроса

```
SELECT
    `mr_main`.`id` AS `id`,
    `mr_main`.`tzp` AS `level`,
    `mr_main`.`tip` AS `type`,
    `mr_main`.`dzp` AS `created`,
    `mr_main`.`dpk` AS `updated`,
    `mr_authors`.`f1` AS `authors`,
    `mr_titles`.`f21` AS `titles`,
    `mr_issn`.`f55` AS `issn`,
    `mr_thematic_section`.`f57` AS `thematic_section`,
    `mr_keywords`.`f58` AS `keywords`,
    `mr_udk`.`f59` AS `udk`,
    `mr_bbkm`.`f61` AS `bbkm`,
    `mr_languages`.`f71` AS `languages`,
    `mr_isbn`.`f75` AS `isbn`
FROM `dev_db`.`mr_main`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_authors` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_authors`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_titles` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_titles`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_issn` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_issn`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_thematic_section` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_thematic_section`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_keywords` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_keywords`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_udk` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_udk`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_bbkm` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_bbkm`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_languages` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_languages`.`b_id`
LEFT JOIN `dev_db`.`mr_isbn` `mr_isbn` ON `mr_main`.`id` = `mr_isbn`.`b_id`
WHERE (
    `mr_authors`.`f1` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_titles`.`f21` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_issn`.`f55` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_thematic_section`.`f57` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_keywords`.`f58` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_udk`.`f59` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_bbkm`.`f61` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_languages`.`f71` like 'Абай'
    OR `mr_isbn`.`f75` like 'Абай'
)
GROUP BY `mr_main`.`id`
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Выполняется почти 3 секунды и это долго, тоже самое при поиске с условием начало 'Абай%'
Индексы созданы FULLTEXT и также пробовал MATCH AGAINST особо разницы не вижу, можете помочь с построением запроса для ускорения?

Comment: А по `b_id` индексы есть в таблицах?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, во всех таблицах есть индекс на b_id

Comment: если вы ищите по равенству или `x%` то вам обычный индекс на полях нужен. И какой смысл тут имеет группировка, если нет никаких агрегатов?

Comment: и неплохо бы чтобы сей индекс включал и `b_id` поле.

Comment: @teran смысл group by в том что в других таблицах есть на один b_id по несколько записей и чтобы не брать их в счет, делаю group by. Может быть и неверный ход

Comment: План выполнения (explain) покажите. И кстати fulltext индекс работает только со специальными операторами match. А like он ни как не ускоряет. И я бы вообще подумал над какой то общей поисковой таблицей, где будет id книги, текст и из какой из таблиц он взят. Что бы в запросе не надо было делать такое количество join. Вести такую таблицу видимо триггерами на остальных таблицах

Comment: @Mike да, тоже так думал и видимо придется такую промежуточную таблицу создать